# Lenovo T440s Fingerprint reader in Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, login, hardware, authentication, thinkpad

I just got my new Lenovo T440s and installed Fedora 20 with Gnome 3 on it. Everything runs smoothly, except for the fingerprint reader. Its got a Validity VFS5011 (138a:0017) device which is not yet officially supported by `libfprint`, but there is [experimental support available](https://github.com/abbradar/fprint_vfs5011).

I installed this version of `libfprint` from source and also build the standard [fprintd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/fprintd/) and [pam_fprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/pam_fprint_v0.2/). In the Users section of the Gnome settings, I now have an option to enable fingerprint login. I enroll my fingerprint and get a "Your fingerprint was successfully saved. You should now be able to log in using your fingerprint reader." message. However, I'm not. The login screen prompts me for my password as usual. The LED indicator on the fingerprint reader is not blinking.

In a terminal, I can check my fingerprint using `fprintd-verify` and it works. Enrolling the finger via `fprintd-enroll` also works and seems to be the same thing as the actual enrollment from the system settings.

**Update**

From the `pam.d` files, two already include `pam_fprintd.so`, one is `fingerprint-auth`, the other is `system-auth`:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

Also, I think the bunch of `gdm-*` files could be relevant as it's my understanding that `gdm` is the Gnome login screen? However, non of them has `pam-fprintd.so` in it and adding it to e.g. `gdm-fingerprint` had no effect.

Comment: I don't have a fingerprint reader anymore, but I would check the pam.d settings that the fingerprint reader is enabled.

Comment: Some of the resources [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Integrated_Fingerprint_Reader) might help.

Comment: Which pam.d setting would that be in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all, I fixed the problem at least partially. Apparently,

```
yum install fprintd-pam
```

did the trick. Now, I can use the fingerprint reader for sudo authentication and removing a screen lock but *not* yet for the initial login screen (which I think is quite weird, since the login screen and the screen lock prompt look pretty much the same). Any further answer on how to achieve this is still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have a T410 w/o the reader but I'd check out this page to see if there is anything there that can help: [Fedora Wiki - Features/Fingerprint](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Fingerprint).

I'd also start poking around the [ThinkWiki T440 category](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category%3aT440), I didn't see anything specific to this model there, but you can often go up and down a few models to find relevant information.

Also of note I found this forum from Lenovo where someone was asking the same question as you (same model different distro - Ubuntu 13.10). [Ubuntu 13.10 on a T440 - Wifi, Sound, Fingerprint reader and TrackPoint issues](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Ubuntu-13-10-on-a-T440-Wifi-Sound-Fingerprint-reader-and/td-p/1346853).

Comment: The Fedora Wiki page is terribly outdated. As I wrote, my problem is not to get the fingerprint reader working at all. It's about convincing the login screen to accept fingerprint authentication.

Comment: Thus, I don't think the issue is hardware specific. I suspect my  manual installation of fprint to be somehow incomplete.

Comment: @Jonas - yes yes, I wasn't implying a hardware issue, but with thinkpads there, in the past, has been custom software one's had to install to make things on them work, so I was directing you to those resources on the off chance that they may be helpful. This issue is difficult for ppl who do not have either a Thinkpad or a scanner to reference, since the problem is localized to having one.